# What is the time complexity of searching through dictionary key values while using the key work *in*

Tags: python, dictionary, time-complexity

Question:

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

My Solution:

What I did was set up a dictionary and iterate through the list of 
the given numbers (O(n)). While I am doing this I am also checking if the desired number is in the dictionary(0(1)). So the time complexity of the solution is O(n).

My solution works but I am new to Python and I don't understand the time complexity of **nums[i] in cache.keys()**. When writing the code I was thinking that **nums[i] in cache.keys()** would take O(n) time to find nums[i] in the list of keys thus making the time complexity O(n^2). But the results of my solution look like its getting around O(n) time. This leads me to believe that **nums[i] in cache.keys()** is taking O(1) time. I was wondering if this is correct, and if someone could explain how this is happening.

```
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        cache = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            b = target - nums[i]

            if nums[i] in cache.keys():
                return [i, cache[nums[i]]]

            cache[b] = i;
```

[runtime results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8YLC.png)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries are implemented as hash tables/maps, which have average O(1) performance for look ups. Internally, they have the same implementation as `set`s.

To further improve performance, replace

```
if nums[i] in cache.keys():
```

with

```
if nums[i] in cache:
```

---

Also, you can make an improvement with `enumerate` (which is more Pythonic):

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    cache = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(nums):
        b = target - x

        if x in cache:
            return [i, cache[x]]

        cache[b] = i;
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I was adding an extra step, thank you! :)

Comment: @toastmachine No problem. If my answer helped you, be sure to mark it as accepted by clicking on the grey checkmark to the left. That way, your question will be marked as solved.